# Spinning Word Search

Tags: code-golf, string, grid, word-search

### Introduction:

Pete likes doing word search puzzles. Despite that, he has trouble searching for words vertically, (anti-)diagonally, or reversed. Because of that, he'll always search for the words left-to-right, and rotates the entire puzzle in increments of 45 degrees clockwise.
In addition to that, he'll also always search for the words in (alphabetical) order.

### Challenge:

Given a word search grid and a list of (alphabetically ordered) words, output how many rotations are necessary to find all the words.

#### Brief explanation of what a word search is:

In a [word search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_search) you'll be given a grid of letters and a list of words. The idea is to cross off the words from the list in the grid. The words can be in eight different directions: horizontally from left-to-right or right-to-left; vertically from top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top; diagonally from the topleft-to-bottomright or bottomright-to-topleft; or anti-diagonally from the topright-to-bottomleft or bottomleft-to-topright.

**For example:**

```
Grid:
 ABCD
 EFGH
 IJKL
 MNOP

Words:
 AFK
 BCD
 FC
 PONM
```

Here, the first string `AFK` can be found diagonally from the topleft-to-bottomright; the second word `BCD` horizontally from the left-to-right; etc.:

```
AFK    BCD    FC     PONM

aBCD   Abcd   ABcD   ABCD
EfGH   EFGH   EfGH   EFGH
IJkL   IJKL   IJKL   IJKL
MNOP   MNOP   MNOP   mnop
```

### Challenge example:

If we take the same example grid and list of words above, we find `AFK` after 7 clockwise rotations of 45 degrees; `BCD` after 1 more rotation; `FC` after 1 more rotation; and `PONM` after 3 more rotations. So the result for the example grid and four words will be `12` (7+1+1+3).

Here a visual representation of these steps:

```
            A                    M                    P                    D
           E B                  N I                  L O                  C H
ABCD      I F C      MIEA      O J E      PONM      H K N      DHLP      B G L
EFGH  →  M J G D  →  NJFB  →  P K F A  →  LKJI  →  D G J M  →  CGKO  →  A F K P  ⮌
IJKL      N K H      OKGC      L G B      HGFE      C F I      BFJN      E J O
MNOP       O L       PLHD       H C       DCBA       B E       AEIM       I N 
            P                    D                    A                    M

      1           2        3           4        5           6        7  A F K
 BCD                                                                             8
      9     F C
                  10       11          12 PONM
```

### Challenge rules:

- Input can be in any reasonable format. The input-grid could be a character-matrix; list/stream of lines; taken from STDIN; etc. The same applies to the list of words.
- The inputs are guaranteed to only contain regular letters (in the same casing, unless you prefer otherwise).
- You're allowed to take the inputs in uppercase; lowercase; mixed case; or even as 0- or 1-based alphabet indices as integers if you'd want.
- You can assume the input-words will always be in alphabetical order.
- You can assume the words will always be present in the grid, and will only occur once.
- All words are guaranteed to have at least two letters (because single-letter words could be found in multiple directions, adding annoying edge cases).
- You can assume neither the grid nor list of words will be empty.
- No need to deal with the remaining letters or partial overlapping of word. Just look for the words one at a time and output the amount of 45 degree clockwise rotations that are necessary.
- The grid will not necessarily be a square, but it's guaranteed to be a rectangle.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases:

```
Inputs:
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
MNOP

AFK
BCD
FC
PONM

Output: 12
```

```
Inputs:
ABC

AB
ABC
BC

Output: 0
```

```
Inputs:
AB

BA

Output: 4
```

```
Inputs:
WVERTICALL
ROOAFFLSAB
ACRILIATOA
NDODKONWDC
DRKESOODDK
OEEPZEGLIW
MSIIHOAERA
ALRKRRIRER
KODIDEDRCD
HELWSLEUTH

BACKWARD
DIAGONAL
FIND
HORIZONTAL
RANDOM
SEEK
SLEUTH
VERTICAL
WIKIPEDIA
WORDSEARCH

Output: 39
```

Comment: Related challenges: [Diamondize a matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77219/diamondize-a-matrix/203697) (single 45 degree rotation); [Word Search Helper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75334/word-search-helper) (output the left-to-right lines of all eight rotations); [Wordsearch Solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3383/wordsearch-solver/) (speaks for itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>26 22</s>  21 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)! (Use the outer-product quick, `þ` rather thank `€Ɱ`.)

```
ŒdU$ŒḌƭƬw€þ§T€F’ŻI%8S
```

A dyadic Link accepting the Wordsearch on the left and the sorted word-list on the right that yields an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY8/TkMxDMb3HiOCrQdgdWO/PitpXDkpkYrYYEHdEVvVmakbJ2ApOxISA@j1HvQi4SVVJ/vnP58/Pz1uNi@lDPuH1dWw//t8PX4cD8@n3eH3@@c9jbE7bd@GL76@iaWUO5NvSRNb8N5MpkZFoOt8hFklsMqeIQlUCijoJGS0lVAdRRFEV0mIlmuae86VFpG5FyBte@DVqbKSVnKCjIRqsVJPPkdPq9Sbyf3oZgbWZdDWQ4a5BGi@Og7neVFeS0jnqsLoaVGzSNR8XLSm5vJWzTM7XtKo10AUI4HaevIf)**

#### How?

This would need tweaking to handle multiple instances of a word in the Wordsearch (would need to account for multiple results in the result of `T€`) but luckily, we don't need to handle that.

```
ŒdU$ŒḌƭƬw€þ§T€F’ŻI%8S - Link: Wordsearch grid, G; word-list W
       Ƭ              - collect input (initially G) while distinct applying:
      ƭ               -   alternating calls to:
   $                  -   ...1: last two links as a monad:
Œd                    -           anti-diagonals
  U                   -           reverse each
    ŒḌ                -   ...2: reconstruct from forward-diagonals
          þ           - table - i.e. [[f(o,w) for o in orientations] for w in W]:
        w€            -   first index of w in each row of o
           §          - sums (sum each of the orientation results)
            T€        - truthy (1-indexed) indices of each
              F       - flatten
               ’      - decrement
                Ż     - prepend a zero
                 I    - forward differences
                  %8  - modulo eight
                    S - sum
```

Comment: I think `€Ɱ` can be `þ`

Comment: Yep, thank you @ovs

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 149 bytes

Expects `(m)(a)`, where `m` is a matrix of characters and `a` is a list of lists of characters.

```javascript
m=>a=>a.map(w=>t+=m.some((r,y)=>r.some((_,x)=>j=~[..."21036785"].findIndex(d=>w.every((c,i)=>(m[y+~-(d/3)*i]||0)[x+d%3*i-i]==c))))*n-(n=j)&7,t=n=0)|t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVBda8IwFH33V4iwkWjt3GRzLxFik2rW2pTUraCUIbaOim1FxQ8Q/7orbo7bjTEW8nIO9557zpmNN@PVZBkv1vU0C6PTlJwS0h7nX0/GC7Ql7XWNJPoqSyKEltoek/byE71quxzNyHGk63rl7rbRfGg93lcCfRqnoUjDaIdC0t7q0SZa7hGaaHE@jpLRvnaso/CmiatxcDg08GhXC6@a1bgeB4RMcP6qaR2lZIavW9qapKSBD@vTJEtX2TzS59kbmqJRqVw@n6Udg1UC7QK52e0BKJ4sG8C@I91KUAow2DctMFAUMw0AXOn0z7u4VPrVy3fxDhDInRYu/VesQ//Y8F@4GgiD2jCykpKapu0VrRhK2IIOJAWkwySzpOMzaJMpi3tSMgZbkpy7Q961hQ@79YToScoV1KS2spQSiitAWpIJxpkqdN3jtu/Z/HnQ@xHbsHyq4CwTtCsdCmOawimoSSWG0hkUZhTNI/YB4XEOY13OfxGXPgHlC0u4PDcAOamYx6kyPqzj0zs)

#### How?

For each word \$w\$, we look for a starting position \$(x,y)\$ and a direction \$d\$ from the string `"21036785"` for which the word is matched along the following vector:

$$(dx,\:dy)=((d\bmod3)-1,\:\lfloor d/3\rfloor-1)$$

Hence the following directions for each \$d\$:

$$\begin{matrix}0&1&2\\3&&5\\6&7&8\end{matrix}$$

We define \$j\$ as the ones' complement of the index of \$d\$ in the string, which gives:

$$\begin{matrix}-3&-2&-1\\-4&&-8\\-5&-6&-7\end{matrix}$$

(NB: We use the ones' complement so that the inner `some()` is not triggered when `findIndex()` returns \$-1\$.)

Given the previous orientation \$n\$ (starting with \$n=0\$), the number of 45° clockwise turns that are needed to reach the new orientation is:

$$(n-j)\operatorname{AND}7$$

We add the result of the above expression to the accumulator \$t\$ and update \$n\$ to \$j\$.

Comment: Maybe this failed on [`AB/BA`, `AB`](https://tio.run/##VY3PCoJAGMTvPYUIxbe6bpb05/IJdesZZAlx11hxd0PFFKRXty3q0DCX38zAVHmft0Wj7l1krJBzibPGNHdmOr/DA9MuRM1aqyVAQ0eCafOlKx0cVfjMGGP@dhMn@8Nx53NWKiMuRsgBBKYPJnvZjAAFVW4OOhvDZwRinZBA8WmKSTaEYpkEKlIcsSBOgYnAYEVWB9qhwZhM3VxY09pastreoIRs4Xmf29PZ5/QH59MbOPmvXUAW8ws)?

Comment: @tsh This doesn't look like a valid input grid, as the words are guaranteed to only occur once (5th rule).

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.9/), <s>265</s> 260 bytes

-5 thanks to KevinCruijssen

### Golfed code

```python
def f(G,W):
 r=0;f=range;g=len
 for w in W:
  while any(w in l for l in G)<1:r+=1;m=g(G[0]);H,G=G[:],["".join(G[j][i-j]for j in f(max(i-m+1,0),min(i+1,g(G))))[::-1]for i in f(g(G)+m-1)]if r%2 else["".join(H[~j][i]for j in f(g(H)))for i in f(g(H[0]))]
 return r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/RboIwFH3nKxqSJW3ERbY3HA@VVmhAaoobiYQHk4HWABrm4nzZr7te3JatT@ece8/pucfLaXfoHq/X16pGNQ6dnHgW6v3JtPb7Tbetplu/qToL1YcenZHuUG7m6LzTTYU23QUPWjOMG4AheXK9fuS709bf4rCYlGQaOaEfFl7pFLZ9vz/ozuj7stDjfQm@Pfhq3G4@sB63I9eZEKc1S9pAE0HMKzxv7A7L@rYM@qgdu6TUNervHlDVvFW/8VHxCfl/07c4Mjn/EiIoR0pzbnV67zvUX4@97k64xha27PyFq5UIaJLYjmUrKel8nmR0BowGSiSCriQFljLJYpnmLADGVMwzKRmLgUnOl2seJiIHtsiEiCTlavDRRMVKCcUVsFgywThTAQMW8STPEv68imyLONBnRoM4p2qYMkFDmdKh2VykN4dUYi3T1U1V1LRaAMo4H5p8pxn0cxjgXMRiyU3eQKRiGacqgE8tQq5f)

### Formatted and commented code

```python
def find_rotations(grid, words):
    rotations = 0
    for word in words:
        while not any(word in line for line in grid):
            rotations += 1
            if rotations % 2 == 1:  # If rotations is odd, rotate rectangular grid by 45deg
                old_grid = grid[:]  # Keep a copy of the old grid
                new_grid = []                                  #
                for i in range(len(grid) + len(grid[0]) - 1):  #
                    new_line = ""                              #
                    for j in range(                            #
                        max(i - len(grid[0]) + 1, 0),          # Equivalent to first list comprehension
                        min(i + 1, len(grid))                  # Rotates rectangular grid by 45deg
                        ):                                     #
                        new_line += grid[j][i-j]               #
                    new_grid.append(new_line[::-1])            #
                grid = new_grid[:]                             #
            else:                   # If rotations is even, rotate copy of old rectangular grid by 90deg
                                    # (Much easier than rotating diamond-shaped grid by 45deg)
                new_grid = []                                  #
                for i in range(len(old_grid[0])):              #
                    new_line = ""                              # Equivalent to second list comprehension
                    for j in range(len(old_grid)):             # Rotates rectangular grid by 90deg
                        new_line += old_grid[~j][i]            # (Rotates old_grid because that is the last rectangluar grid)
                    new_grid.append(new_line)                  #
                grid = new_grid[:]                             #
    return rotations
```

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! Nice first answer, +1. :) If you haven't seen it yet, [tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) and [tips for golfing in all languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read through. Three minor things to golf: `>0` can be removed after `r%2`; the space at `[i] for` can be removed; `-j-1` can be `~j`. [You can also move the test code to the footer in your TIO-link](https://tinyurl.com/n7xvu39z), so it's clearer what the actual code-block is

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 206 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k,N=0,E=enumerate:k and f(n,k[(A:=any(any(all(-1<(Y:=r+(R:=[0,*[-K]*3,0,K,K,K])[N%8])<len(n)>-1<(Z:=c+R[N%8-2])<len(_)!=C==n[Y][Z]for K,C in E(k[0]))for c,H in E(_))for r,_ in E(n))):],N+1-A)or N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFdj9owEHzfX5E@VIkhVFzv5RRdKpnYgOsQI4c2OtIo4o7kGhFMFIIqfj21gRaqyrK1M7Mf1mxz7H7u1ONT055OpV@vtq/rlaXcjRv5Q5f6hTpsi3bVFd7GWqm1VTpaSx3s@St1dM63rp3Bw7Pz4vlt35Genw7dXjrgWe/RHbrcnAyl0cenDD3XhXIU@mLSl57/1peGH3y@Kjn64Ae@r9KXLF1m5a61uBtYlbKos0mHGUKGenOnFyq/4NbNL1ghhLzMjfoPA4y0EJ3WRWmVedMWXXd0toe6q@pKFfl7W61d64Z/7dr1HnlgNW2lOqd00rRnhMwy/U1kBvxb/2nf1FXn2D@UjbL/mt2rCAG8Vu95pZpDt7d8y7ZtPAoI0PFkCuwrD2EWiTkAHnMw/DiAuYhmoJmRvuYdXcEI6yD5TuWCBTgMQQqBx@Mw1hoOJAsZXggMERGEiyghARDJaSwEIRwEpfMlnYQsgVnM2FRgKnXzUHIpmaQSuCCMUCL1F6Y0TOKQfltMzcyAJ1gSIAxPRIRDGLNIpwjJliJaaCyxnjiDmFIO16o/X4SEcTanuhQSIUlMsQym2oCbQebY2qKzPXld7c8epfV9ho0umzBruFmZARj2VmjkuzZ6oX@X37vx6PQb)

Recursive solution.

### Explanation

Initialize `N`, the number of rotations. Set it to 0.

At each iteration, we attempt to identify the first word in `k`, the list of words to find, by going through every cell in the grid and pointing in the direction that `N` corresponds to. For instance, if `N` is 0, meaning the grid is not rotated at all, we go 0 rows down and 1 column to the right, `len(k[0])` times at each cell.

If such a word is identified, then we delete the first element and recall `f` with `n`, the now smaller `k`, and the same `N`. `N` does not change, because there might still be words in the same orientation.

If no such word is identified, then no deletion is done and instead we recall `f` with `n`, the same `k`, and an incremented `N`.

Eventually, `k` will be empty, and in such a case, we return `N`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 406 bytes

```py
R=range
L=len
e=lambda b:'\n'.join(map(''.join,b))
r=lambda b,x,y:[b[x][y]]+(r(b,x-1,y+1)if x and y<L(b[0])-1 else[])
def s(b,c=1):
 t=[[i[::-1]for i in zip(*b)],[[i]for i in b[0]]][L(b)==1]
 yield[r(b,i,0)for i in R(L(b))]+[r(b,L(b)-1,i)for i in R(1,L(b[0]))]if c%2 else t
 yield from s([t,b][c%2],c+1)
o=lambda b,w:w!=[]and w[0]in b and 1+o(b,w[1:])
g=lambda b,w,u:1+g(next(u),w[o(e(b),w):],u)if w else-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVPRbtowFH2ev8KrNMUppqqhD1O0PJjElCwhRoYNqZ41kRJYJpqgJCiwn2d2YLRat76Yy7nn3HtOZG8P9Y8i73/clsejcMtFvk5B5G7SHKTuZvGULBcwcaxvuXXzs8hy9LTYIutU48S2QXkh4T0@ODKReyUPSnVQiTTUJfjQIXa2gnu4yJfw8ClCibxVdpfAdFOlUtlgma5gpcmPLrEdAGtXykw6TpeoVVHCDGY5/JVt0XViK6xbz6gZpJTUE23XJQrAQ5ZultIszvCtfeEJZCi26rQtU2tb2cs@wWdbttJWHz/0WnOwPo@Eq7J40h5ljRMldVvhR50KFM/hG6d570plMjZ6kHHXBiadQu9sJHF00vULPt45pLNGebqv0c7WjAKl2hlubEfhnfliTWuiS45JsSiX7tXVFR14PmDD@xEIPocRGMd8olHQ9smZcAF60CDzr0zMAo9GERCc0@EwmtIBoJ4IooDOOAWxz/2Qx3PfA74I2ZRz3w8BZ2zywO6jYA7G0yAYccoEBTQSoRCBYAKE3A985gttaMSi@TRiX2ajy@6@WQ3owJwNgS6UFh2GFoaWTmB@hp45JzweWwo0vRNjYDAd4cQzjb4rrQH1wjkVrcwP6D2PadSOCOIWG3ERPPB4dkIF1YHGppoy1m48WTPVn09h6nkQBhOm57V/uPCnjApvZJbetW4GVNfmatbF9zYTqvTtfFem9a7Mobw2D2GTVTWGq2xTpyWKizzFsLqptpusRubF2Po6gcrEr9BlSnvqh7Mts7xG678bGDYE/4P/XwUxkt5rCXlD0zeau9ea/huantH0X2t6RnP8DQ)

Comment: `y<L(b[0])-1 else` can be `y<~-L(b[0])else` for -1

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 59 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υι≔⟦⟧ηＷＳ⊞ηιυＦ⁸ＦＬυＦＬθ«ＪλκＵＭη⎇⁼μ⪫ＫＤＬμ✳ιωιμ»⎚ＩΣＥη﹪⁻ι∧κ§η⊖κ⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU7JbqQwED2nvsJHW2LukXJybHfawWBkmEFKlAPqdhqrwXQAZ9Fovp0xWZVLLn5@VfWWXduMu6HpluWpdZ1FWPpTmMt5dP6ACUFFmFocEuTIBdBpcgePb@8S1Eb6g6B9ExRxOOMQf/fDiPA5Qa@orD/M0ZV85w@R/4Wz69CfqgF3CTpG4VnWnNjQ943fr66VHX0zvmDxEJpuwn2CrgfncWHtkbvR7mY3@A@/niToa@hIpE/r4xLUk2j9D1hnmxF/FmXNNOMy9DhmrmHZsA/dgDPnw4SjisYOxwiz9Hv7vF5wuxttb/1s44aQ1f18BXKxLPUfYSrJqFJgtKabjSrpJVBmpJK00hRyrnmq85oz4CYVpdacp6CFKG7ElZI1ZKWUW02FoUCVSY2RRhhINZdccMM4bIWqSyV@V1uAS8rSmhoOXNIrnVMFG5nHE23kjc6ryA2NiRmUQqTwrvqoCLVMZSGiFGpteCmoYVtYfj12/wE) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Read in the grid.

```
≔⟦⟧ηＷＳ⊞ηι
```

Read in the words.

```
υ
```

Output the grid.

```
Ｆ⁸
```

Loop over each direction.

```
ＦＬυＦＬθ«Ｊλκ
```

Loop over each cell.

```
ＵＭη
```

Looping over each word...

```
⎇⁼μ⪫ＫＤＬμ✳ιωιμ
```

... if it matches the word in the current direction starting from the current cell, replace it with the current direction.

```
»⎚ＩΣＥη﹪⁻ι∧κ§η⊖κ⁸
```

Pairwise subtract the directions, reduce them all modulo `8`, and output the sum.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 158 bytes

```python
f=lambda G,L,*H:L>[]and 1-(d:=L[0]in" ".join(map("".join,G)))+f(d*G or[*zip(*((x:=H)or[(x:=x+s)+g+s*len(G)for g in G])[::-1])],L[d:],*[G*(H==()),H][d])
s=" ",
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVFRa9swEH6/XyHyYslxy8pehsEFxZJlTYoV5LSGuqKkeMk8XMfEGbT986mcZbSIO@4@3Xd3fDe8HX/v@@8/hsPptE26zctzs0Ei0lGYx/q2dpu@QTdXuIkTXX9zbT9Ds@s/@7bHL5sBz/7FkSCEzLe4CQXaH@rwvR1wiPFrnOTE51PwOh/JfDcfw@5XjwXZ7g9oh9oeCUfqOL66ccRFum5iF4W1CHGeJJiQKHd14wiMiZ8aneC53T21/fD3OKIEBUFAFykDnokc5E@lYVmYFQDNFEx4lsLKFEvwyMLb5BeXZEF9UN1zu5Yp1RqsMTTLdOn/aGqllnRtKBTMMGWKiqXArOKlMYwpMJyvHrjQsoJlKWVuKLe@ubbKWmm5BWWYZJxZv0LOdVVqfrfOp5mpqqhlwCQVpqAaMln4EmPlgynWPrfUT1xCybmCC@v/ilBJJVfcU6EylpWc2jT3AlyPQ9cecfDYTy8gAGd5nrp2PGtUd18rAoIm3btJ908pHcCE@pNP@Bd@DEgkl2Oenbg088d2gIZD2x/xFnviJ376AA)

Takes a sequence of tuples of characters for the grid and a sequence of strings for the search list.

Test harness nicked from @ophact.

#### How?

More or less does actually rotate the grid and then searches in normal row major order.

90° rotations are implemented as up down flip followed by transpose (aka `zip`).

If we first shear by prepending a linearly (w.r.t. line number) increasing amount of white space and then do the same 90° rotation we get essentially the same lines as we would have doing a 45° rotation.

The main "loop" is recursion. `G` is the current grid `L` the leftover word list and `H` alternates between being empty and a backup of `G` because every 90° rotation must be based not on the current `G` but its predecessor.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 144 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,b,d=0,[w,...r]=b)=>w?a.some((r,y)=>r.some((c,x)=>w.every((p,i)=>p==a[d%4?d<4?y-i:y+i:y]?.[x+i-'00122210'[d]*i])))?f(a,r,d):f(a,b,-~d%8)+1:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLRcppAFH2/X7EvGdmKDNo8tKTE2cAatyDrrLbMxDgTApjSMcIAiTpJ@ut2QYw2fWB3795zzj33sr@D56AI8yQrO6s0ine7hakE6r0ambo6W6uapuVz8x6bl@t@oBXpY6woubqVcd5Eobqpslr8HOdbRcnURIaZKVVm0dl5P/p23t92EmPblt/89VXHs0076bR0vdvr9bp6axbNPyVzjHF/IQvnaoSNRe2g8yc6@4LbXUPflXFRhkERF8hEd8BW2VNZGECuLBvo4HoI7LvjwsjjYwAycKC6H1gw5t4IgD@VEm6gbg9OmRJ5Ve/V8YDRTyEAV@SYOj@m/J9UTJlFXBcE52QwcCeVliWYy8iUE/Bsbjvc820LbOHQCee27QCndHxDr13mw2jC2JATKggQVzhCMEEFONxmNrWFdD@krj9x6Y/psHJhOT4RNtiMXHOPuDBgnoRwwW64N5WxILLiCCaUOtCwDhbBZw4bU0kFnwt7QomwhseuPn@FO63Mk0cFa0W2TEql1XTZwtoiWZZxrmyQeYk2WHsMMiWrzi@AUJiuihLNkgqsorSWm8u/k31Qawq18MWR9JAnkYrWaR4VFaXW@EC7Xd2u9pw8Lp/yVV0ToYpp1OsR2No7CytnM/lcwzlWa3BdwNhv/8k3rPWBtT6w4k0Wh3Iy7X1P1eXbBbxJL/D@CrVFmtMg/KUoL@ikGbUhozf875j2UrLVhXICfx9Juoy1ZfqgHGCm2QgdBHFtYPcX)

TIO is 147 bytes as `?.` syntax is not available on it.

Input grid as 2d character array. Input words as an array of array of characters. Output a number. `f(grid: string[][], words: string[][]) -> number`